# MVC2 Validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-2

My application uses MVC validation explained here:
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/validating-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

And it works fine with both server and client validation when the form is posted. However my problem is that I would like to have client validation on one of the fields before the form is posted. So when the TextBox loses focus it is validated directly.

Comment: Could we see some code please?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by using jQuery validation on the field that is validated before the form is posted.

Answer (score 0):

You must use JQuery validations so that it will validate before posting. It also highlights those area where validation fails.